# Who is the community liaison for SFF from SE?

Tags: support, stackexchange

At some point, Stack the company seemed to have an attempt to have community liaisons for all of the sites. My impression was that Brett White was SFF point of contact though I could be wrong.

Is such a policy still in place? If so, who is the current liaison for SFF and how can they be contacted if it's not Brett?

Comment: This is a bit of an "X-Y problem" question... my real question is "how can I run an idea by SE liason + moderators without posting it publically to avoid possible major ridicule if the idea is shot down :)  Flagging for a mod attention seems like a poor approach - it's the wrong tool and there is a small text size limit.

Comment: Include your comment as part of your question.

Comment: @Keen - Sorry, I disagree with that. I figure that the question as stated is useful to the community overall, whereas the comment is very localized and useless to anyone but 2 people on the site. I'll post a separate question if you prefer, though, but will be greatly miffed if it's closed as "too localized" :)

Comment: @Keen - http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2175/what-is-the-appropriate-mechanism-to-reach-sff-management

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The community team splits the sites in the network among themselves, but these assignments change over time so we avoid publicizing the specific CM.

To reach us, post here on meta, grab a moderator to ask them to contact us, or use the contact form linked at the bottom of any page.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to remember to bump this Q in a couple of months in case the answer changes by then.

Comment: @DVK Did you bump it? What happeded with this?

Comment: @Mooz - I don't recall ever hearing that the divvying up happened. Since my proposal which served as the impetus for this stalled out temporarily, I didn't follow up yet.